# python on heroku. Get SIGHUP error

Tags: python, ruby, heroku

On working through HEROKU's guide to getting Python app to run on HEROKU and one first creates a hello world program ostensibly using python and flask and runs it locally using Foreman. I get an 'unsupported signal SIGHUP' from Ruby/Gems/foreman/engine. I am Running Win7. Anybody else hit this problem or have any ideas ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to a known issue on Win7: https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/pull/219

Heroku just released a new version of the [Foreman gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/foreman) (v0.48) that resolves this issue. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running locally, you can also just run the flask app from the command line using python, skipping Foreman altogether.  This is how I run locally on my Windows 7 machines.